# Writing {value} +- {uncertainty} in matrix. How does that work with sympy?

Tags: matrix, sympy, elementwise-operations, uncertainty

I have two 6x6 matrices. Here I'll just show the first two rows and columns:

```
import sympy as sp
values = sp.Matrix([[-0.403900000000000, 0.158730000000000], [-1.52350000000000, -1.87937000000000]])
uncertainties = sp.Matrix([[0.000600000000000000, 0.000280000000000000], [0.000270000000000000, 0.000170000000000000]])
```

I want to get a matrix where the `[0][0]` element would look like "`-0.4039 +- 0.0006`". And this for every element, so that i can export this matrix to latex.
How do I do this?

I tried using

```
f"{values[i][j]} +- {uncertainties[i][j]}"
```

for all i and j, but that just gave me `value[i][j] - uncertainty[i][j]`

I couldn't find this on the internet. Do I need to look into latex for loops? Or can I do that in sympy?
I jsut really really don't want to manually put the uncertainty behind every matrix element in multiple matrices.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matrix cannot hold strings but it can hold Symbols with arbitrary names. Does the following produce the right latex?

```py
>>> str(Float(.4309).round(4))+' +- 0.006'
'0.4309 +- 0.006'
>>> Matrix([[Symbol(_)]])
Matrix([[0.4309 +- 0.006]])
```

If so then it's just a matter of knowing what decimal to round to and then putting the Symbols in place. I would probably have a values matrix and an uncertainties matrix and a function that puts them together and outputs the special symbol matrix. The `uncertainties` [package](https://pythonhosted.org/uncertainties/) might be of use in creating the strings.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! $sp.symbols(str(value) + "\pm" + str(uncertainty))$ did the trick!